# How do i change the color of the <a>anchor link in bootstrap's navbar-inverse class

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Here's the problem that i'm facing, the color of anchor link in the navbar-inverse class by default is set to a greyish color.
When i make changes in the css, im only able to target the link color when it is active or in focus or when hovered.
The moment i click outside (the link goes out of focus) it changes back to grey.

```
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus
    {
        background:  aquamarine;
        color: white ;

            }
```

How do i specifically target color attribute of the anchor element when its not active in the navbar ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the fact that you are specifying an anchor tag with active class, but anchor might not have active class, therefore you are seeing it as grey.

First two blocks are targeting the anchor `<a>` tag without the `.active` class. And the last one that you had in your question, is essentially the same with `.active` class.

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background: aquamarine;
}
```

Comment: LOL the question seems dumb now. Thanks a lot Andrej.